# Does jQuery's html() method auto-join the argument if it's an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While experimenting, I came across this.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#result').html(['<p>This is inside an array</p>', '<em>This is second item in array</em>']);
</script>
```

When the page was reneded, I could see the following markup in the browser console:

```
<div id="result">
   <p>This is inside an array</p>
   <em>This is second item in array</em>
</div>
```

Does this mean that jQuery is running `array.join("")` in the background if the argument/parameter supplied to the .`html()` method is an array?

I couldn't find this mentioned in the documentation and hence was curious to know more on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When passed anything other than a string, `.html()` empties the element and uses `.append()` to append the HTML instead, which, when given an array, inserts the HTML strings in the array in the order they appear. This behavior is only documented for [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append).

The fact that `.html()` uses `.empty().append()` internally when passed an argument that's neither a string nor a function is not stated in its documentation page. The closest is a statement that jQuery empties the element in much the same way [when given a function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function), although that does just follow the same `.empty().append()` code path.

Note that this does not actually call `Array.join()` in the way that you would expect. It appends elements represented by each string in the array one by one, rather than joining all the strings first before inserting it via `innerHTML`. So, for example, the following with a missing (optional) `</p>` end tag behaves identically — it does not insert a `p` containing an `em` child, but a `p` and an `em` as siblings, in that order:

```
$('#result').html(
  [
    '<p>This is inside an array',
    '<em>This is second item in array</em>'
  ]
);
```

Comment: Great answer. *"This behavior is only documented for `.append()`."* And not very thoroughly even then. It just says it accepts an array, not what it *does* with the array.

Answer (score 3):

Extending @BoltClock's answer, `html` method's definition in `jquery.js` file is as below:

```
html: function( value ) {
    return access( this, function( value ) {
        var elem = this[ 0 ] || {},
            i = 0,
            l = this.length;

        if ( value === undefined && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
            return elem.innerHTML;
        }

        // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
        if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) &&
            !wrapMap[ ( rtagName.exec( value ) || [ "", "" ] )[ 1 ].toLowerCase() ] ) {

            value = jQuery.htmlPrefilter( value );

            try {
                for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
                    elem = this[ i ] || {};

                    // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                    if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                        jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
                        elem.innerHTML = value;
                    }
                }

                elem = 0;

            // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
            } catch ( e ) {}
        }

        if ( elem ) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
},
```

So this checks for `if (typeof value === "string"` and when it fails it skips the portion of directly setting the value as `innerHTML` and `if(elem)` executes after making sure its an `element` does what is specified in @BoltClock's answer. i.e.

```
this.empty().append( value );
```

and the definition of the `empty` goes as

```
// Remove all callbacks from the list
empty: function() {
       if ( list ) {
          list = [];
        }
        return this;
},
```

Comment: To be precise, it's not an `else`, it's `if ( elem )`. It guarantees that the element, on which we want to execute `html` function, exists. And it refers only to the first element of the matching elements of the selector while the `if ( typeof...` is applied to all the matching elements.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ agreed. I missed that..Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.. :)